# Adding <img> onclick adds 0 instead of <img> element

Tags: jquery

I have a div in html I use instead of input, it's this one:

```
<div class="crazytext" name="msg" id="chatty" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I have jq code that should, when clicking a smiley, add it do the div. Smileys are all represented like this

```
 <li><a class="smilepick" href="smile_1"><img src="emoticons/smile_1.png" class="emoticon_pick"></a></li>
```

And there's 30 of them. They are defined as vars, like so:

```
var smilies = { 
    smile_1 : '<img src="/emoticons/1.png"/>',
  smile_2 : '<img src="/emoticons/2.png"/>'
...
}
```

And here's the adding code:

```
 $(".smilepick").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#chatty').val($('#chatty').val()+(' ')+$(this).attr('href')+(' ')); 
        var el = $("#chatty").get(0);
        var elemLen = el.value.length;
        el.selectionStart = elemLen;
        el.selectionEnd = elemLen;
        el.focus();

        var linkValue = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#chatty").html((function(link) { return function(i, v) {
                return v.replace(link, smilies[link]);  
        }; })(linkValue));

        return false;
});
```

Instead of adding the  element to the div, where it should (if some text is there, should add it to the end of the text, much like hangouts does), it simply replaces all text in the div with a 0, or it doesn't do anything when the div is empty. I can't figure for the life of me what I'm doing wrong. If I remove the bottom part of the code, one that's suppose to convert any "smile_x" to `<img src="smile_x">`, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please?  Might be a little easier that way.

Comment: First of you're using `val()` to get the contents of a `contenteditable` element. That won't work, `val()` is used to get the values on `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements. You should use `text()` or better `html()`.

Comment: Yup got it thanks =)
@JoshBeam didn't get the chance to finish building it, Roko got it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aBaHEYoc/1/edit)***

```
var $chatty = $('#chatty');

$(".smilepick").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
   $chatty.html( $chatty.html()+' '+ smilies[myHref] +' '); 

});
```

Comment: YES! That's the one, cheers man. I failed on more than one place :)

Sorry Roko, one more, can I find the `<img>` element in a string such as "blah blah blah `<img src="1.png">` blah blah" and replace that `<img>` with src value?

Comment: @SamFisher there's issues with this code, and that's the way a user can add a smiley at the **caret position** (store that range position before an smiley selection) instead of adding to the end, additionally you should explore how to properly set again the caret at that place after the action and apply focus.

Comment: Oh right I should explore that one. Thank you, I'll look into it and post it once I find out how to do that =)

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Thank you, I'll see how I can add it here :)

Comment: @SamFisher exactly, give it a try. Good luck! (P.S. I've found some answers here on SO, you might also able to find one that best suits your needs)